Ciphering services not available error on pysnmp v3 walk
I can run this command from the command line:
snmpwalk -v3 -m +MY-MIB-ROOT -m +MY-MIB -l authPriv -u MYUSER -a SHA -A "XXXXXXXX"  -x AES -X "XXXXXXXX" 1.2.3.4 .1.3.6.1.4.1.52330.6.1.2

I am trying to implement the same command in a python script using pysnmp:
import asyncio
from pysnmp.hlapi.v3arch.asyncio import *
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# snmpwalk -v3 -m +MY-MIB-ROOT -m +MY-MIB -l authPriv -u MYUSER -a SHA -A "XXXXXXXX"  -x AES -X "XXXXXXXX" 1.2.3.4 .1.3.6.1.4.1.52330.6.1.2


# Load MIBs
mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['file:///usr/share/snmp/mibs'])
mibViewController = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)

loadedModules = mibBuilder.mibSymbols.keys()
print("loadedModules:", loadedModules)

async def run(varBinds):
    snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()
    while True:
        print("A")
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = await bulkCmd(
            snmpEngine,
            UsmUserData(
                'MYUSER',
                'XXXXXXXX',
                'XXXXXXXX',
                authProtocol=usmHMACSHAAuthProtocol,
                privProtocol=usmAesCfb128Protocol,
            ),
            await UdpTransportTarget.create(('1.2.3.4', 161)),
            ContextData(),
            0,
            50,
            *varBinds
        )
        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
            break
        elif errorStatus:
            print(
                f"{errorStatus.prettyPrint()} at {varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] if errorIndex else '?'}"
            )
        else:
            for varBind in varBindTable:
                oid = varBind.__getitem__(0)
                print(oid)
        varBinds = varBindTable
        if isEndOfMib(varBinds):
            break
    return

asyncio.run(
    run([ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.52330.6.1.2'))])
)


I get this error:
Ciphering services not available

I am running the script within a virtual environment on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.4 (Plow)
$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2024.8.30
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
idna               3.10
Jinja2             3.1.4
MarkupSafe         2.1.5
pip                24.2
ply                3.11
pyasn1             0.6.1
pycryptodomex      3.20.0
pysmi              1.5.0
pysnmp             7.1.4
requests           2.32.3
setuptools         53.0.0
urllib3            2.2.3


If anyone else comes across this issue, the latest release makes use of the cryptography package so it worked after I installed that:
pip install cryptography

This was version 43.0.1 at time of writing.
pycryptodomex can be removed

It would be helpful if you included the precise version (of both packages) for future reference.

You should accept your own answer. BTW, pycryptodomex is obsolete and no longer needed.
